# Monad Transformers and lift function

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Why isn't it necessary to use lift for executing a function in an internal monad transformer environment, except for IO? I mean, if I have StateT over WriterT and WriterT over ReaderT, why can I do this?

```
tell $ {- any code here for the Writer -}
foo <- asks {- This for the reader -}
and so on...
```

instead of

```
lift $ tell $ {- code ... -}
...
```

Is there an special explanation or it is only the way the Monad Transformers were written?

Comment: Look at [all the instances `WriterT` has](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#control.i:WriterT).

Comment: Note that if you use the `transformers` library instead of `mtl` you will have to explicitly `lift` everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the Monad Transformer Library (MTL) recognizes that it's quite common for you to stack monads in just that way so they don't define `tell` as just some function `(Mondoid w) => w -> Writer ()`.

Instead they have [`MonadWriter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html#t%3aMonadWriter) which is defined as *a typeclass with tell as a function in it*. Then they define a ton of instances of `MonadWriter`: `ReaderT`, `IO`, `Writer` (duh) etc. And thus you avoid the annoying repetition of `lift.`.

This is quite common, any monad transformer (in MTL) will have a `Control.Monad.***.Class` which has this sort of typeclass.

Comment: I understand!, I didn't read the instances of the Monads. Thank you